# How to get rows even if count is 0? Only 1 table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I want the count even if the count is 0. My current query is

```
SELECT `id`,count(0) as `fetchpc` FROM `user` WHERE pid in('4,6,7,8') GROUP BY `id`
```

But it returns only those id where count is greater than 0

**Edit:**
the values used for in('4,6,7,8') are first fetched from database in another query. And then using a script rows are converted to 4,6,7,8.

So all the values are present in the database.

Also it is possible that the values returned can go upto 100+ values.

Comment: I don't have any other table related to it. I tried a lot with left outer join but it needs another table.

Comment: As per your query. suppose id: 6 is not present in table then how can a SQL will produce data to you.

Comment: To produce the data in your query either data has to be present in table or you can split the input values into rows and then join the splitted rows to main table. It seems type of INT for ID column hence input value ('4,6,7,8') will not produce any rows. Input integer for IN condition should not have data enclosed in single quote. It should be like (4,6,7,8)

Comment: You should edit your post to clarify what IDs actually exist in the table already and what output you get with current code.  If you were expecting output for IDs that do not exist in the table then you need to learn that you cannot select rows that do not exist and how to modify your table and/or query to conform to the rules of the road.

Answer (score 3):

You could left join this query on a "fictive" query that queries these IDs as literals:

```
SELECT    ids.id, COALESCE(cnt, 0)
FROM      (SELECT 4 AS id
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 6 AS id
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 7 AS id
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 8 AS id) ids
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
           FROM   fetchpc
           GROUP BY id) t ON t.id = ids.id
```

Comment: what if the values to be passed are over 100 values

Comment: when I try this query it gives an error...fetchpc does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a derived table.  I would recommend:

```
SELECT i.id, COUNT(u.id) as fetchpc
FROM (SELECT 4 as id UNION ALL
      SELECT 6 as id UNION ALL
      SELECT 7 as id UNION ALL
      SELECT 8 as id 
     ) i LEFT JOIN
     `user` u
     ON u.id = i.id
GROUP BY i.id;
```

From a performance perspective, this is *much* better than aggregating first (in a subquery) and then joining.  Basically, the aggregation (in that case) has to aggregate *all* the data and afterwards filter out the unnecessary rows.

This formulation filters the rows first, which should speed the aggregation.

Comment: will union work if there are over 100+ values that have to be checked.

Comment: Also this query returns 1 for all the fields even though there is no row matching the criteria.

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal . . . (1) This will work for 100+ values.  (2) The `COUNT(u.id)` returns `0` if there ar eno matching values in `user`.

Comment: how to modify "SELECT `id`,count(*) as `fetchpc` FROM `user` WHERE pid in('4,6,7,8') GROUP BY `id`"

if in where clause id is replaced with pid

Comment: No...I meant to say that the query I mentioned in my previous comment, if in it I want to get the count when count is 0..then what can be done?